# Исключения в методе с++

Tags: c++, исключения

Добрый день!
Хочу, чтобы исключение генерировалось в методе класса, а обрабатывалось в другом месте, поправьте.

```
class A
{
public:
    int i;
    void ARA()
    {
        if(i != 11)
        {
            try
            {
                throw 1;
            }
        }
        cout << "ARA " << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.ARA();
    catch(int a)
    {
        cout << "number:  " << a << endl;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Делаю такой бред, куда нужно вставить catch, чтобы по логике было то же самое, но работало, спасибо).

Comment: Оберните просто `a.ARA` в `try`, а из самого метода `try` уберите, оставьте там просто `throw`.

Answer (score 4):

исправил все ошибки:)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    int i;
    A (): i(0) {} // конструктор для инициализации i
    void ARA()
    {
        if(i != 11)
        { // try здесь не нужен
                throw 1;
        }
        cout << "ARA " << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
   try{ // а здесь нужен try.
      A a;
      a.ARA(); // здесь нужны скобки
    }
    catch(int a)
    {
        cout << "number:  " << a << endl;
        return 1; // return должен возвращать целое
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: да, я это уже поисправлял.

Comment: и i не обязательно инициализировать, конструктор по умолчанию это сделает.

Comment: хм, странно, но не инициализирует(

Comment: @fortunado: инициализирует или нет, зависит от типа инициализации (которых в C++ очень много). Смотрите тут:

* [default initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization)
* [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization)
* [zero initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization)
* [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization)
* [direct initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization)